# Database schema restores by Sql job

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, jobs

I'm planing to do a database backup and restore by using SQL Job. My database size is to large and I want to backup and restore my schema only.

By using this code I can set up SQL Job. Can anyone help me to backup and restore my schema only?

```
BACKUP DATABASE [pubs] 
TO DISK = N'c:\temp\backups\pubs_full.bak' 
WITH INIT, SKIP, CHECKSUM
GO

RESTORE DATABASE pubs_RestoreTest
FROM DISK = N'c:\temp\backups\pubs_full.bak'
WITH MOVE 'pubs' TO 'c:\temp\backups\pubs_RestoreTest.mdf',
MOVE 'pubs_log' TO 'C:\temp\backups\pubs_RestoreTest_log.ldf'
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server contains no facility to only backup the schema of a database.  Backup-and-restore can *only* be used to restore the entire contents of a database or, in the case of piecemeal restore, individual filegroups of a database, assuming there are multiple filegroups.

However, there are multiple tools available that can be used to export and synchronize schemas between versions of databases.

Just a couple of options, listed alphabetically:

[ApexSQL SQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx)
[dbForge Schema Compare](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/)
[Idera SQL Comparison Toolset](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlcomparisontoolset)
[SQL Server Data Tools - MSBuild Support for schema comparison](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available/)